# Are the audio and video elements for html5 inline or block elements?

Tags: html

I was wondering if the audio and video elements block or inline elements?

Answer (score 3):

I ran the following web page in Chrome 11...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<audio></audio>
<canvas></canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];
alert(getComputedStyle(c, null).display);
</script>
```

...and it reported `inline` for both canvas and audio. For what it's worth.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tchalvakspam/tary5hdj/

Checked video as well, all display as inline by default.

Answer (score 3):

Like many (most?) HTML elements it depends on the context.  In this example they are 'inline' elements (what are now called 'phrasing' elements):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<p><audio></audio><video></video></p>

</html>
```

In this example they are 'block' elements (what are now called 'flow' elements):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<p></p>
<audio></audio>
<video></video>
<p></p>

</html>
```

Whether or not your browser is conforming to the spec is another issue entirely.

For further reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories